# make sure img div loads before video div

Tags: jquery, html, function, fade

I have a page where when you click one out of a set of buttons, and image pops up and then fades as a video plays. The problem is that it works on the first click, but on the second on, the div with the image loads *after* the video loads. How can I make sure it appears before the video starts to load? the script (simplified) is

```
$('li, .thumbs').on('click', function() {
    myVideo.load();
    myVideo.play();
    $('#myVid').bind("loadstart", function() {
        $('#MyT').fadeIn(0);
    });
    $('#myVid').bind("playing", function() {
        $('#MyT').fadeOut(500);
    });
});​
```

Comment: @gdoron I'm looking. the real code has been getting a little messy, so I'm cleaning it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using onload function for images. This ensures images are loaded before anything else takes place

[I wrote a blog post, how to do that](http://aniruddhaloya.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-ensure-images-are-loaded-before.html). You can put your video load and other functions inside the onImgLoad function as described in the blog. This will ensure your image loads and appears before video begins.

Answer (score 1):

Set timeout to the play:

```
$('li, .thumbs').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();
    }, 200); // 200 ms, you can custom it as you wish.

    $('#myVid').bind("loadstart", function() {
        $('#MyT').fadeIn(0);
    });
    $('#myVid').bind("playing", function() {
        $('#MyT').fadeOut(500);
    });
});​
```

Comment: it works, but still, the movie starts to load before the div with the image comes up, which is the problem. This is still alot cleaner than what I had before though

Comment: @Nata2haMayan2. Then move the `load` inside the `setTimeout` as well. Updated,

Comment: I'm guessing that the `fadeIn` should be binded to the `'click'` at that point as well?

Comment: @Nata2haMayan2. It may, is it that important? Just play with it until you find an pleasant output.

Comment: yeha. It's for an ios5 device, so its very awkward when the video loads. This is really the last thing needed to make the whole page work...